# The ng-file-upload doesn't work with MEAN.JS app when injection is used

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, ng-file-upload

Error thrown:

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngFileUploadProvider <- ngFileUpload <- MyCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=ngFileUploadProvider%20%3C-%20ngFileUpload%20%3C-%20MyCtrl
    at http://192.168.99.100:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://192.168.99.100:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4511:19
    at Object.getService [as get]
```

When Controller is defined as following:

```
(function ($, angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('myapp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

  function MyCtrl(
    $scope,
    $q,
    $stateParams,
    Upload,
    $timeout
  ){

    var vm = this;

    function setup(){

      vm.stateParams = $stateParams;

      //set scope variables here

      viewApi();
    }

    function viewApi(){

      vm.uploadImage = function(file, errFiles) {
        vm.uploadedThumbnail = file;
        vm.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
        if (file) {

          file.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
            data: { file: file }
          });

          file.upload.then(uploadSuccess, uploadError, uploadEvent);

        }
      };
    }
    ... 
    setup();
  }

  MyCtrl.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$q',
    '$stateParams',
    'ngFileUpload', // Note that 'Upload' doesn't work either
    '$timeout'
  ];

}(window.jQuery || window.$, window.angular));
```

I tried `ngFileUpload` and just Upload with the same result. 
All dependencies are declared and loaded. 
This has something to do with injection pattern not working properly.

Comment: bower dependency declaration:     "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.12"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `ngFileUpload` to your module definition, like this:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngFileUpload', 'ui.router', 'other.dependencies', ...]).controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
...
```

Comment: Actually not 'ngFileUploadProvider' but 'ngFileUpload' as per documentation but it doesn't solve the problem - it creates a different problem.

Comment: As for the other error, you can only declare your module once. All of its dependencies must be included in that original array. I am pretty sure that the $state provider comes from ui.router. So, you need to include that as well as all other dependencies in the initial module array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually as I discovered the solution is relatively simple:

angular.module('myapp', ['ngFileUpload']).controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

It resolves the problem above but creates a new problem by removing application state provider:
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myapp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider

So we solve one problem by creating a new one.

And new question now: how to add 'ngFileUpload' dependency without overwriting other application dependencies.